# Why Recharts draws undefined category on yAxis?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts

Can't figure why `recharts` draws some `undefined` category on `yAxis`.

[image]

Here is a link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/liubko/x1yoboc7/455/

```
const data = [
  {name: '01-01', alice: "alice"},
  {name: '01-02', alice: "alice", aliceActive: "alice"},
  {name: '01-03', bob: "bob", alice: "alice", aliceActive: "alice"},
  {name: '01-04', bob: "bob", alice: "alice", aliceActive: "alice"},
  {name: '01-05', bob: "bob", bobActive: "bob", alice: "alice"},
  {name: '01-06', bob: "bob", bobActive: "bob", alice: "alice"},
];

const categories = ["alice", "bob"];
const SimpleLineChart = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <LineChart width={600} height={300} data={data}>
        <XAxis dataKey="name" />
        <YAxis type="category" />            
        {categories.map(cat =>
          [
            <Line type="step" dataKey={cat} stroke="yellow" />,
            <Line type="step" dataKey={`${cat}Active`} stroke="green" />,
          ]
        )}            
      </LineChart>
    );
  }
})
```

*I want to have a chart consists of straight horizontal lines. xAxis - is `time`. yAxis - is a `user`. But each user can be in a different state through time.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That bug has been fixed in v0.21.0

https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/528#event-980022510

Comment: @ErickMwazonga please add a link here if you submitted an issue to github

Comment: I haven't submitted an issue yet, should I submit one?

Comment: I guess it's the most convenient way to let maintainers know about the problem

Comment: Here it is https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1604, I have realized it was also raised here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49909093/recharts-skip-a-bar. An example to experiment with is https://codesandbox.io/s/72jon1w971

Answer (score 0):

What about adding `ticks` to the `YAxis` component?

```
<YAxis
  ticks={categories}
  type="category"
  padding={{top: 30, bottom: 30}}
/>
```

Using this it doesn't show the empty ticks. I don't know if this is the solution you are looking for or I'm just hidding the real problem but I hope it helps.

Comment: It doesn't render the tick itself but reserves an extra space on a chart for it. It's better seen when there are more than two categories. http://jsfiddle.net/liubko/x1yoboc7/457/