# Recharts Skip a Bar

Tags: recharts

I have some data that looks like this:

[{
    a: 15,
    b: 30,
    c: 25,
    d: 12
},
{
    a: 15,
    c: 25,
    d: 12
}]

I want to render a barchart that skips the space in between a and c if b is undefined, but will still render b if it is defined.

Basically like the two bar chart groups in this image where the orange bar is skipped because there is no data for it

[image]